# Google Calendar API v3 - authenticate with application owned (non-real user) account

Tags: google-calendar-api

I've been looking into Google Calendar API as a way to manage calendar/event information for my application. It looks like Google Calendar API is setup to connect to a Google user's account. After you have access to the user's account you can add/update/manipulate calendar and event information. I want this same functionality but on a "user account" that is virtual.. not owned by a real user but an account created specific to my application to use. Is this possible?

The docs mention Google will show a consent page to the user to integrate with the users calendar, how would I go about coding the authentication for my calendar if I (the application) owns the account and calendar?

Comment: Have you gotten any further with this? Please clarify. What type of credentials does your app have?

Comment: Yes, I found that you can use a service account to access calendars that you own. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service account, which will belong to a project in your dev console, and you can give it credentials to access its own calendar.

See [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)